# Why isn't my button working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton, ibaction

I have created a UIButton; actually, a few buttons, and I have initialized them and set them up in the

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

method. My issue now, is connecting them to the method that I have created. I have created a typedef enum to replace the numbers for the tags of my buttons with names to certain situations. I do not know if this is the issue or what, but I am confused on why when I press the button(s), they are not working. My code is below.

My enum:

```
typedef enum {
DiseasesStrepThroat = 1,
DiseasesFlu         = 2,
DiseasesChickenPox  = 3,
DiseasesSmallPox    = 4,
DiseasesMeasels     = 5,
DiseasesCommonCold  = 6
} DiseasesTagNumber;
```

I have initialized all of the UIButton objects; as well as my IBAction in my .h file already, so I don't have to worry about that part.

Here is my view did load

```
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];    
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 700, 768, 125)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 125);
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

//////////////////////////////////////////
//                                      //
//      creating all the buttons        //
//                                      //
//////////////////////////////////////////

// strep throat
strep = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
strep.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 110, 100);
[strep setTitle:@"Strep" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[strep setTag:DiseasesStrepThroat];
[scrollView addSubview:strep];

// the flu
flu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
flu.frame = CGRectMake(130, 10, 110, 100);
[flu setTitle:@"Flu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[flu setTag:DiseasesFlu];
[scrollView addSubview:flu];

// chicken pox
chickenPox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
chickenPox.frame = CGRectMake(250, 10, 110, 100);
[chickenPox setTitle:@"Chicken Pox" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[chickenPox setTag:DiseasesChickenPox];
[scrollView addSubview:chickenPox];

// small pox
smallPox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
smallPox.frame = CGRectMake(370, 10, 110, 100);
[smallPox setTitle:@"Small Pox" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[smallPox setTag:DiseasesSmallPox];
[scrollView addSubview:smallPox];

// measels
measels = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
measels.frame = CGRectMake(490, 10, 110, 100);
[measels setTitle:@"Measels" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[measels setTag:DiseasesMeasels];
[scrollView addSubview:measels];

// common cold
commonCold = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
commonCold.frame = CGRectMake(610, 10, 110, 100);
[commonCold setTitle:@"Common Cold" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[commonCold setTag:DiseasesCommonCold];
[scrollView addSubview:commonCold];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:strep, flu, chickenPox, smallPox, measels, commonCold, nil];
for(UIButton *b in array) {
    b.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
}


//&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&//
//                                      //
//      CREATING ALL THE TARGETS        //
//                                      //
//&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&//

[strep      addTarget:self action:@selector(showDiseasesWithTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[flu        addTarget:self action:@selector(showDiseasesWithTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[chickenPox addTarget:self action:@selector(showDiseasesWithTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[smallPox   addTarget:self action:@selector(showDiseasesWithTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[measels    addTarget:self action:@selector(showDiseasesWithTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[commonCold addTarget:self action:@selector(showDiseasesWithTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

and now my IBAction method

```
- (IBAction) showDiseasesWithTag:(NSInteger)senderTag {

switch (senderTag) {
    case DiseasesStrepThroat:

        a = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"H" 
                          message:@"yo" 
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [a show];
        break;

    case DiseasesFlu:
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {

        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
        break;

    case DiseasesChickenPox:
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {

        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
        break;

    case DiseasesSmallPox:
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {

        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
        break;

    case DiseasesMeasels:
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {

        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
        break;

    case DiseasesCommonCold:
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {

        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
        break;

}
}
```

To clear anything up, all the UIView animation and completion blocks are not completed. I am mainly focused on the first case. Is it because I have the first case as a 1? When I had it set to 0, it still did nothing.

The actual issue with everything, is when i press the first UIButton in my UIScrollView, I am able to press it, but what happens is the button does nothing regarding the IBAction method. It doesn't seem to be calling it at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you sure the action method does not fire?  Have you set a breakpoint in `lldb` or set an `NSLog()` call?

Comment: I just placed a NSLog() in the 1st case position, and it doesn't call the function because I see no console output.

Comment: You mean you placed it above the `switch()` statement, don't you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you are simply using the wrong argument to the action method.  It should be:

```
- (IBAction) showDiseasesWithTag:(id)sender {
    NSInteger senderTag = [sender tag];

    switch (senderTag) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Under iOS the target method can have one of three different *signatures*:

```
- (IBAction)actionMethod;
- (IBAction)actionMethod:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)actionMethod:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

but never:

```
- (IBAction)actionMethod:(NSInteger)senderTag;
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I haven't really tried using many different types of arguments, so this is a new learning experience, but thanks for helping me solve that seemingly simple error!